# Problema al recibir datos en Android con JSON, PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, json

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para un control de un restaurante, cabe recalcar que soy relativamente nuevo en esto, y la mayoria de lo que hago es con consultas por internet.

Este es el problema, tengo este Script de PHP en el cual recibo una variable de  **NOMBRE** con el nombre de un platillo de comida, y retorna el id el nombre, precio y lo que pueden ver.

```
<?php 

// Getting the requested id
$NOMBRESEND = $_GET['NOMBRE'];

// Importing database
require_once('connectdb.php');

// Creating SQL query with where clause to get a specific employee

$sql = "SELECT c.NOMBRE AS NOMBRECATEGORIA, p.* FROM plato p, categoria c WHERE p.ID_CATEGORIA=c.ID_CATEGORIA AND (p.NOMBRE=$NOMBRESEND OR c.NOMBRE=$NOMBRESEND)";

// getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// creating a blank array 
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

// Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
array_push($result,array(

"ID_PLATO"=>$row['ID_PLATO'],
"NOMBRE"=>$row['NOMBRE'],
"PRECIO"=>$row['PRECIO'],
"DESCRIPCION"=>$row['DESCRIPCION'],
"NOMBRECATEGORIA"=>$row['NOMBRECATEGORIA'],

));
}

// displaying in JSON format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

El script funciona bien. El problema es en Android.
Mando el nombre del platillo con esta función:

```
public String sendGetRequestParam(String requestURL, String id){
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL+"\""+id+"\"");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String s;
        while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(s+"\n");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

En donde `requestURL` es la dirección del script de PHP y `id` es el nombre del platillo.

Si en esa variable `id` mando por ejemplo "pizza" el valor retorna correctamente y me muestra el archivo JSON con el platillo, pero si mando por ejemplo "Hamburguesa de pollo" no me devuelve ningún JSON. Lo raro es que si lo hago con postman, por ejemplo y escribo "Hamburguesa de pollo" si me devuelve el JSON como se puede observar en esta imagen:

[image: Prueba con POSTMAN]

En el debug salen estos datos en ambos casos.

En este le mando "Ravioles" y como se puede observar en el String `s` devuelte el JSON con los datos de los ravioles.

[image: Android 1]

Pero al Mandarle por ejemplo "Hamburguesa de pollo" no devuelve nada y no guarda los datos en el String `s` y tampoco recibe el JSON con los mismos.

Comment: ¿Te ocurre con todos los datos que tienen espacios en blanco? Quizá los está recibiendo así: `Hamburguesa%20de%20pollo`. En ese caso deberás reemplazar el valor `%20` por un espacio antes de pasar el valor a la consulta. Ejemplo: `$url = trim($url);
$url = str_replace ( ' ', '%20', $url);` donde `$url`  sería la dirección de la petición, o lo puedes aplicar sólo a `$NOMBRESEND`. También puedes probar a escribirlo así a ver qué tal: `Hamburguesa+de+pollo`. Quizá también tendrás que revisar la declaración de ese campo en la BD.

Comment: @A.Cedano  Muchas gracias por tu respuesta en efecto, reemplaze los espacios por signos "+" y funciono correctamente. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

al parecer es debido a los espacios en blanco.

te diría que pruebes .. Quitando los espacios

intenta esto..

en android .

```
URL url = new URL(requestURL+"\""+id.replace(" ","")+"\"");
```

en tu php

```
 $sql = "SELECT c.NOMBRE AS NOMBRECATEGORIA, p.* FROM plato p, categoria c WHERE p.ID_CATEGORIA=c.ID_CATEGORIA AND (REPLACE(p.NOMBRE, " ", "")=$NOMBRESEND OR REPLACE(c.NOMBRE, " ", "")=$NOMBRESEND)";
```

cuidado con reemplazar los espacios con signos.. no me confiaría mucho en ello.

Answer (score 1):

### El origen del problema

En el caso que planteas, las URL se están codificando según el estándar [**`RFC 3986`**](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html), el cual explica en su apartado 2.1 que las URL que contengan caracteres no permitidos serán sustituidas por el signo `%` seguido de su octeto binario. El apartado pone precisamente como ejemplo el espacio en blanco, cuyo octeto binario sería `20`, por lo que una URL que contenga espacios en blanco, dichos espacios son sustituidos por `%20`.

Por lo tanto en peticiones cuya URL se crea así en tu aplicación:

```
http://www.example.com/verPlato.php?NOMBRE=Hamburguesa de pollo
```

Si se aplica `RFC 3986`, el servidor recibirá la URL así:

```
http://www.example.com/verPlato.php?NOMBRE=Hamburguesa%20de%20pollo
```

---

### Soluciones

Varias soluciones son posibles, sea del lado de la aplicación, sea del lado del servidor.

#### A. Del lado de la aplicación

Puedes reemplazar los espacios en blanco por el signo `+`, haciendo algo como esto:

```
String urlPost="http://www.example.com/verPlato.php?NOMBRE=Hamburguesa de pollo";
urlPost = urlPost.replaceAll(" ", "+");
```

Esto producirá una URL así, la cual es totalmente válida para el caso que nos ocupa:

```
http://www.example.com/verPlato.php?NOMBRE=Hamburguesa+de+pollo
```

---

#### B. Del lado del servidor

Puedes dejar que la aplicación envíe la URL codificada según la norma `RFC 3986` y trabajarla en el servidor.

```
$urlPost=( empty($_GET["NOMBRE"]) ) ? NULL : urldecode($_GET["NOMBRE"]);

if ($urlPost){
    require_once('connectdb.php');
    //Resto del código
}else{
    //Indicar el error en forma de array
}
    //Emitir la respuesta con json_encode
```

Puedes hacer también un reemplazo en lugar de usar `urldecode`. Pero, no vale la pena renunciar a una función que existe precisamente para eso. Nótese que del lado de la aplicación no tendría ningún sentido decodificar la URL, porque la misma se codifica precisamente al ser enviada al servidor.

Tu código de servidor adolece de algunos fallos de seguridad y de lógica:

- Debes implementar consultas preparadas ya que tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Recomiendo que leas sobre el tema y corrijas ese grave error.
- En el cuerpo del código PHP he escrito un flujo coherente. Mediante un operador ternario verifico si la clave `NOMBRE` no está vacía en el GET y en ese caso propongo emitir un mensaje de error para que el usuario de la App no se quede en blanco cuando por mal uso no haya escrito datos en el campo de texto que debería recoger el nombre.