# Envio de frase a web service mediante JSON

Tags: php, android, android-studio, json

Tengo un pequeño problema a la hora de enviar una frase mediante JSON a un web service, si envío un string sin espacios como String nombre="Jose";, no hay ningún problema, pero al intentar enviar toda una frase, la consulta no se realiza. Cual seria la forma de enviar un frase con espacios como
String frase = "La casa del monte";

```
String frase="La casa de martin es roja";

String url="http://sapito.org/Archivos/File/registrys2.php?frase="+frase.trim();


jsonRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

Los datos los recibo en un archivo PHP.

Gracias de antemano y saludos.

Comment: El problema es que `trim()` sólo borra los espacios en blanco que están en los extremos del String. Igual, si hubiese funcionado como esperabas, habría sido complicado volver a agregarle los espacios en el web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de enviar la frase debes reemplazar los espacios en blanco por `%20`

```
String frase="La casa de martin es roja";
String frase2 = frase.replace(" ","%20");
String url="http://sapito.org/Archivos/File/registrys2.php?frase="+frase2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Respondí hace tiempo a un caso parecido al tuyo, planteado en esta pregunta: [Problema al recibir datos en Android con JSON, PHP y MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104561/29967)

Dado que allí el OP parece haber abandonado la pregunta, pongo casi aquí aquella misma respuesta, porque explica citando la fuente el origen del problema, dando luego algunas soluciones.

### El origen del problema

En el caso que planteas, las URL se están codificando según el estándar [**`RFC 3986`**](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html), el cual explica en su apartado 2.1 que **las URL que contengan caracteres no permitidos serán sustituidas por el signo `%` seguido de su octeto binario**. El apartado pone precisamente como ejemplo el espacio en blanco, cuyo octeto binario sería `20`, por lo que una URL que contenga espacios en blanco, dichos espacios son sustituidos por `%20`.

Por lo tanto en peticiones cuya URL se crea así en tu aplicación:

```
http://sapito.org/Archivos/File/registrys2.php?frase=La casa de martin es roja
```

Si se aplica `RFC 3986`, el servidor recibirá la URL así:

```
http://sapito.org/Archivos/File/registrys2.php?frase=La%20casa%20de%20martin%20es%20roja
```

---

### Soluciones

Varias soluciones son posibles, sea del lado de la aplicación, sea del lado del servidor.

#### A. Del lado de la aplicación

Puedes reemplazar los espacios en blanco por el signo `+`, haciendo algo como esto:

```
String frase="La casa de martin es roja";
frase = frase.replaceAll(" ", "+");
```

Esto producirá una URL así, la cual es totalmente válida para el caso que nos ocupa:

```
http://sapito.org/Archivos/File/registrys2.php?frase=La+casa+de+martin+es+roja
```

---

#### B. Del lado del servidor

Puedes dejar que la aplicación envíe la URL codificada según la norma `RFC 3986` y trabajarla en el servidor.

```
$urlPost=( empty($_GET["frase"]) ) ? NULL : urldecode($_GET["frase"]);

if ($urlPost){
    //Trabajar con la URL
}else{
    //Indicar el error en forma de array
}
    //Emitir la respuesta
```

Puedes hacer también un reemplazo en lugar de usar `urldecode`. Pero, no vale la pena renunciar a una función que existe precisamente para eso. Nótese que del lado de la aplicación no tendría ningún sentido decodificar la URL, porque la misma se codifica precisamente al ser enviada al servidor.